# QML-Listview (Cpp-Model) Details-Dialog

Tags: c++, listview, qml, datamodel

EDIT: 26.08.2014 08:20 - Completely reworked question!

What I want to do is:

1. Fill a qml-listview with data from a cpp-listmodel (QAbstractListModel).
2. Open a Dialog that show's more data from the cpp-listmodel by click on a listview-item.

I have two cpp-Classes:

1. DataModelItem with two attributes (listData (displayed in the listview) and detailsData (displayed in the Dialog))
2. DataModel which inherits QAbstractListModel with an attribut QList itemList.

**DataModel.cpp:**

```
QVariant DataModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    DataModelItem *item = m_itemList.at(index.row());
    switch (role) {
    case ListDataRole:
        return QString().sprintf("%.2f", item->listData());
        break;
    case DetailsDataRole:
        return QString().sprintf("%.4f", item->detailsData());
        break;
    default:
        qDebug () << "role not handled";
    }

    return QVariant();
}
```

What I now wanna do is, to display the listData in the ListView. When I click on one ListItem a dialog should appear with the detailsData.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out, that I can't write model.detailsData in my main application, but just detailsData works (I also tried listview.model.detailsData with no effect). Probably someone know why this does not work.

Anyway I found a solution.

Here's the working example:

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 1.1

Rectangle {
    width: 200
    height: 400

    ListView {
        id: listView

        model: dataModel
        delegate: listDelegate
    }

    Component {
        id: listDelegate

        Item {
            id: delegateItem
            width: listDataText.width
            height: listDataText.height
            Text {
                id: listDataText
                text: listData
            }

            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: {
                    console.log(detailsData)
                    itemDetails.details = model.detailsData
                    itemDetails.visible = true
                }
            }
        }
    }

    DetailsDialog {
        id: itemDetails
        visible: false
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
}
```

**DetailsDialog.qml**

```
import QtQuick 1.1

Rectangle {
    property alias details: detailsText.text
    width: 100
    height: 62

    Text {
        id: detailsText

    }
}
```